# Struggling to integrate RecyclerView with ViewModel to maintain state eg on Rotate

Tags: java, android

Am unsure how to correctly use ViewModel with RecyclerView to maintain state on configuration change, eg rotation.  With code as is, rotating the screen does not restore the list to the pre-rotate state, it reverts to the initial blank screen.

Here is my MainActivity with the ViewModel and RecyclerView both set up in onCreate.  I'm using dummy data atm to try to get it working, see addDummyComposerData() which adds the data to the ViewModel and calls NotifyDataSetChanged() on the Adapter:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout mMainTabs;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerList;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mListLayoutManager;
    private MyListAdapter mListAdapter;

    private List<Composer> mComposerList = new ArrayList<>();

    private MainActivityViewModel mViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
        mViewModel.SetDataListComp(mComposerList);

        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        mRecyclerList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_list);
        mListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(mListLayoutManager);
        mListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this,mViewModel.GetDataListComp());
        mRecyclerList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

        mMainTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        mMainTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch (tab.getPosition()){
                    case 0://composer
                        addDummyComposerData();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                mComposerList.clear();
                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch (tab.getPosition()){
                    case 0://composer
                        addDummyComposerData();
                }

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void addDummyComposerData(){

        mComposerList.clear();

        Composer composer = new Composer("Albinoni, Tomaso (1671-1751)");
        mComposerList.add(composer);

        composer = new Composer("Bach, Johann Sebastian (1685-1750)");
        mComposerList.add(composer);

        //etc etc

        mViewModel.SetDataListComp(mComposerList);
        mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel class:

```
public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MusicQuery mCurrentQuery;
    private List<Composer> mDataListComp;

    public void SetCurrentQuery(MusicQuery query){
        mCurrentQuery = query;
    }
    public MusicQuery GetCurrentQuery(){
        return mCurrentQuery;
    }
    public void SetDataListComp (List<Composer> list){
        mDataListComp = list;
    }
    public List<Composer> GetDataListComp(){
        return mDataListComp;
    }
}
```

And the ListAdapter:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Composer> composerList;
    private int selectedPos = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    private MainActivity mMainActivityContext;

    private MainActivityViewModel mMainActivityViewModel;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private static final String TAG = "UI Output";
        private String selectedText;
        public TextView mComposerView;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mComposerView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.composer_name);
        }
    }

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<Composer> composerList){
        mMainActivityContext = (MainActivity) context;
        this.composerList = composerList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View mComposerView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.composer_layout,viewGroup,false);
        //mComposerView.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
        return new MyViewHolder(mComposerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
        Composer mComposer = composerList.get(position);
        holder.mComposerView.setText(mComposer.getName());
        holder.itemView.setSelected(selectedPos == position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        if(composerList != null){
            return composerList.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Should I be referencing the ViewModel from inside the Adapter?

Comment: The very first thing you do in onCreate is set the data to an empty list.

Comment: maybe you need take a look at: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `mViewModel.SetDataListComp(mComposerList);` line inside the `onCreate()` method. This is resetting the list on rotation.

**Some explanation:**

1. When the screen rotates, the activity is being destroyed and recreated.
2. This means that the `onCreate()` method will be called again.
3. And because of this, the above line is resetting the list data of the ViewModel.

Only store the list in the ViewModel as this is where the data should be stored, and survives te rotation change. So remove the `private List<Composer> mComposerList = new ArrayList<>();` from the MainActivity. There is no need to store the list in the Activity, only the ViewModel should modify it.

**Solution:**

As for initializing the list, we can do the same in the ViewModel (or we can initialize it in the constructor):

```
// Option 1: Initializing it directly
private List<Composer> mComposerList = new ArrayList<>();

// Option 2: Initializing it via the constructor
public MainActivityViewModel() {
    mComposerList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Next, just modify the list when needed with the `viewModel.SetDataListComp(<list>)` method that you already have. It should update the list inside the view model. Now, when the activity is rotated, the viewmodel still has the list data and can pass it again to the mainactivity (with the `viewModel.GetDataListComp()`method).

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to explain it.  It's basically working now, with a few glitches I hope to be able to iron out :)